# Does Sahih Muslim contain a hadith to the effect of "has Allah not rendered for you the isha prayer in congregation equal to hajj"?

Tags: source-identification, sahih-muslim

In answering [Is there an Alternative to hajj](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40726/17163), I stumbled upon this hadith quoted repeatedly:

> O Messenger of Allah, the wealthy people will have higher grades and will have permanent enjoyment and they pray like us and fast as we do. They have more money, which they give in charity. ”The Prophet, sallallaahu `alayhi wa sallam (may Allaah exalt his mention), replied: “**Has Allah not rendered for you the ‘Ishaa’ prayer in congregation equal to Hajj, and the Fajr prayer in congregation equal to ‘Umrah?**”

It's attributed to "Muslim", presumably meaning Sahih Muslim, by these sites: [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/ehajj/article/172581/righteous-deeds-with-the-same-reward-as-hajj-and-umrah-i), [DailyHadith.co.uk](http://www.dailyhadith.co.uk/forum/index.php?topic=1188.0;wap2), [QuranReading.com](http://www.quranreading.com/blog/deeds-that-are-equal-to-reward-of-hajj/), [Understanding Islam (forum)](http://forums.understanding-islam.com/showthread.php?12637-10-Good-Deeds-that-carry-the-Reward-of-Hajj!), [hunafaatravel.com](http://www.hunafaatravel.com/actions-like-hajj-and-umrah/), [MuslimPress.com](http://www.muslimpress.com/Section-islam-22/82321-performing-actions-that-equal-to-hajj-in-reward), [MasjidKingKhalid.org](http://masjidkingkhalid.org/hajj/things-which-are-equal-to-hajj/), among others.

However, the obvious web searches, e.g. [`site:sunnah.com/muslim hajj congregation`](http://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Asunnah.com%2Fmuslim%20hajj%20congregation) and [`congregation hajj`](https://sunnah.com/search/?q=congregation%20hajj) at sunnah.com, did not identify a reference to it in Sahih Muslim.  (Although it comes up with [Jami' at-Tirmidhi 586](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/6/43), which is listed as da'if.)

**Question**: Does Sahih Muslim contain a hadith to the effect of "has Allah not rendered for you the isha prayer in congregation equal to hajj"?

[duniashuaib.com](http://duniashuaib.com/easy-good-deeds/) instead references it as "Sahih Al Jami 6432".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hadith is attributed to a [Muslim ibn al-Hajjaj](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muslim_ibn_al-Hajjaj) narration, but it is not in his Sahih as the entire version. Most likely, you are referring to the hadith in the "Forty Hadith Nawawi" book (See [Hadith 25](https://www.sunnah.com/nawawi40/25), and see [Sahih Muslim 1006](https://www.sunnah.com/muslim/12/66)).

The additional part:

> #### أو ليس قد جعل الله لكم صلاة العشاء في جماعة تعدل حجة، وصلاة الغداة في جماعة تعدل عمرة
>
> Has Allah not rendered for you the 'isha' prayer in congregation equal to hajj and for the fajr prayer in congregation equal to 'umrah?

is through a weak chain of narration.

This addition is narrated by al-Hafidh Abu Mussa through 'Uqba ibn Abdul-Ghafir through Thabit al-Banani through Abu Hameed al-Taweel al-Basri through Hammad ibn Salama through Affan ibn Muslim through Ahmad ibn Hanbal through Abdullah ibn Ahmad ibn Hanbal through Abu Bakr ibn Malik al-Qati'i. As documented by [Abu Nuaym al-Asbahani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abu_Nuaym) in his book *Hilyat al-Awliya'*, Abu Bakr ibn Malik al-Qati'i is unknown, and Hammad ibn Salama's ability to memorize deteriorated with time; hence, the ruling of weak that you found.

On another note, [Jami' at-Tirmidhi, Hadith 586](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/6/43) is weak as the identity of Abu Dhilal (mentioned in the Arabic chain of narration) is not confirmed. This is documented in the Arabic version, but it is not translated.

Comment: `The hadith is attributed to a Muslim ibn al-Hajjaj narration, but it is not in his Sahih` By this, do you mean that it's misattributed, or that it *is* a narration by Muslim, just not a *sahih* one? (i.e. that Muslim actually narrated more ahadith than were eventually recorded in his Sahih)

Comment: @goldPseudo It is attributed to Muslim and this is correctly so. The hadith is authentic but not up to the conditions of his Sahih book. The addition is neither Muslim's nor authentic.

Comment: Does the statement quoted by goldenPseudo then means it is compiled in an other book of Muslim? If so which one?

Comment: @Medi1Saif — It is in [Sahih Muslim, Hadith 1006](https://www.sunnah.com/muslim/12/66). However, the phrase "narrated by" (رواه) does not automatically translate into inclusion in a book. The phrase "akrajah" (اخرجه) refers to first inclusion in a book (e.g., Sahih Muslim), and the phrase "kharrajah" (خرجه) refers to being referred to in a book by another book (e.g., al-Silsila al-Sahiha).